# Linux - How can I copy files of the same extension located in several subdirectories into a single directly?

Tags: python, linux, bash, csh

I have a folder which has many subdirectories, each with a `*.nr` file in them. There are 1000 subdirectories, each containing at least one `*.nr` file. Is there a quick way to copy all those `*.nr` files into a single directory?

I can write a quick `python` script to iterate through the files, but this seems like overkill if there is a quick command line based way to do it.

I've been googling, but I'm not sure what exact terms I should be googling.

Thanks!

Comment: `os.walk` + `shutil.copyfile` should do the trick.  I guess maybe with a check using `os.path.splitext`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

something like

```
find /path/to/src -name "*.nr" -exec cp \{\} /path/to/dest \;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this may overwrite files in `/path/to/dest` that share the same name, but that's something to be aware of with any solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you're on a system with GNU `cp`, this will do it faster:

`find /path/to/src -name "*.nr" -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t /path/to/dest`

---

Copying all `.c` files under my `src` dir:

```
time find ~/src -name "*.c" -exec cp \{\} ~/src/Cfound/ \;
. . .
real    0m1.838s
user    0m9.530s
sys     0m1.110s

time find . -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t ./Cfound/
. . .
real    0m0.057s
user    0m0.010s
sys     0m0.060s
```

Comment: I know it's faster, but I can never remember the right xargs syntax. In the time it takes me to `man xargs` I can knock out the find -exec line :)

But +1 for the benchmarking effort!

Comment: Thanks man. Btw, any reason for escaping the \{\} rather than using quotes in your exec?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way in bash:

```
for F in */*.nr; do cp $F otherdir/ ; done
```